# Make [x2] and [x-men-2] synonyms

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms

The tags [x2](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/x2) and [x-men-2](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/x-men-2) appear to be about the same movie. The site won’t let me suggest synonyms, so I’ll ask here: should these be made synonyms of each other? <del>I suggest making [x2](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/x2) a synonym of [x-men-2](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/x-men-2).</del>

Edit: Never mind. It isn't possible to synonymize these tags, since they only have two answers total.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since there was only one question in each tag, I renamed [x2](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/x2) into [x-men-2](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/x-men-2).

- It's obvious what the latter means to somebody who isn't familiar with the X-Men franchise.
- Most of our other X-Men-related tags start with "x-men", so it fits nicely.
- It's more likely to show up in autocomplete on an X-Men related question.

I imagine there are probably more questions about the film that need the tag, but I really can't be bothered to go on a mass tagging spree, and I don't want to mess up the homepage.

Answer (score 1):

[Suggested](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/tags/x-men-2/synonyms).

Arguably deleting [x-2](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/x-2) would also work, as they should see [x-men-2](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/x-men-2) when they first type <kbd>X</kbd>

Comment: @amaretto technically correct

Comment: Given that only Richard has any rep on answers with those tags, how will the synonym get approved?

Comment: @amaretto it won't. Arguably it doesn't need to be synonimized with so few questions.

Comment: Oh. If I had known that, I wouldn't have bothered with this post. Someone can just re-tag the question tagged [tag:x2].

Comment: @amaretto Mods can approve any synonym ...

Comment: @randal'thor Could AncientSwordRage have approved his own suggestion? In any case, it doesn't matter for this synonym anymore.